# How many blocks are required for a natural join (R join S)

Tags: database, memory, join

Suppose relations R and S each have 10,000 blocks and they are both indexed on attribute a. How many disk I/O’s are required to compute their natural join? At a minimum, how many blocks of memory are required for this operation?

Comment: That depends on the RDBMS and join algorithm.

Comment: This is an exercise from a DBM class.  I would like to keep the question general but to give context I believe the answer may be 3 * (B(R) + B(S)).

Comment: Are the indexes covering? In that case you'd need to fully read both indexes once doing a merge join.

Comment: Hi usr, What if the indices were clustered?

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as they can provide all rows sorted on a.